# How can I manually instantiate controllers using ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

so, in my "root" controller...

```
$scope.subElements = [
            { heading: "Contact", state: "institution.contact", active: false },
            { heading: "Adapters", state: "institution.adapters", active: false },
            { heading: "Transactions", state: "institution.transactions", active: false },
            { heading: "Organizations", state: "institution.organizations", active: false },
            { heading: "Users", state: "institution.users", active: false }
        ];
```

and in my "root" view...

```
<tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="elem in subElements"
             heading="{{elem.heading}}"
             select="go(elem.state)"
             active="elem.active">
        </tab>
    </tabset>
```

it's working great, but the problem is, the controller is not instantiated until the user clicks on the tab heading. So, the user has to wait for the data needed by the controller to be loaded from the remote endpoint. I'd prefer to have more granular control of data loading, like triggering the other sub-controllers to load in the background and activating their respective tabs when they've completed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: try using a angular service

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the resolve object of your states? From the documentation:

> You can use resolve to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state. resolve is an optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.
>
> If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and converted to a value before the controller is instantiated and the $stateChangeSuccess event is fired.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

For example:

```
$stateProvider.state('institution.transactions', {
    'url': '/institution/transactions',
    'controller': 'transactionsController',
    'templateUrl': 'transactions.html',
    'resolve': {
        'transactions': [
          'TransactionService',
          function (TransactionService) {
              return TransactionService.get();
          }
        ]
    }
});
```

You can now inject the transactions into your controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('transactionsController', [
    '$scope',
    'transactions',
    function ($scope, transactions) {
        $scope.transactions = transactions;
    }
]);
```

Now when changing to state `institution.transactions` the controller will wait with initialization untill the promise returned by the service is resolved. Only then the controller will fire up and the view gets switched. In the meanwhile you could use the `onStateChangeStart` and `onStateChangeSuccess` events to show some sort of progress/busy indicator. See: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

You could also resolve all of your child state dependencies in your parent state, just put them all into the resolve object of that state. They will be available to the childstates:

```
$stateProvider.state('institution', {
    'url': '/institution',
    'controller': 'institionController',
    'templateUrl': 'institution.html',
    'resolve': {
        'contact': [
          'ContactService',
          function (ContactService) {
              return ContactService.get();
          }
        ]
        'adapters': [
          'AdapterService',
          function (AdapterService) {
              return AdapterService.get();
          }
        ]
        'transactions': [
          'TransactionService',
          function (TransactionService) {
              return TransactionService.get();
          }
        ],
        // and on and on and on
    }
});
```